# why my nginx service can not be stopped on my mac?

Tags: macos, nginx

I installed nginx on my mac lion by using homebrew. When i type command:

```
nginx -s stop
```

the service is launched again in a second. how can i stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the `LaunchAgent`, I believe that will keep the service alive if it's not running.

[See launchd.plist man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html)

You can try running  `launchctl stop org.nginx.nginx` or remove the

```
<key>KeeyAlive</key>
<true/>
```

bit from the plist (`~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.nginx.nginx.plist`)

**Update**

Looks like the only way to stop the daemon is to `unload` the LaunchAgent:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.nginx.nginx.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx -g daemon off
```

Comment: Remember to explain the code/commands, not just throwing them as an answer